# Passing data from python to html view in django framework

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have an application where users can enter the news they heard. The entered 'news headline', 'news', and 'time' are stored in elasticsearch NoSQL database. The entered news items are first analyzed with NLP techniques to detect and remove unethical words and again stored in elasticsearch database. After that, I want to show them on a web page in order. I completed the processing NLP task but still, I cannot display all the news items on the web page. for that, I'm using the Django framework.

what I was trying to do was extract the news items from elasticsearch using a for loop and store each news item=`[news headline, news, time]` as a collection of lists inside a list `[[],[],[]]` and pass them to the HTML template.

python code:

```
def news_items(request):
newsData = []

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

for x in range(1, 101):
    results = es.get(index='reporter', doc_type='news', id=x)

    pyData1 = json.dumps(results)
    pyData2 = json.loads(pyData1)

    newsData = pyData2['_source']

    pyNewsData1 = json.dumps(newsData)
    pyNewsData2 = json.loads(pyNewsData1)

    id = pyData2['_id']

    headline = pyNewsData2['newsHeadline']

    newsText = pyNewsData2['newsText']

    date = pyNewsData2['date']



    list = [id, headline, newsText, date]

    newsData.append(list)

template = 'AppOne/news.html'
return render(request, template, {'nd': newsData})
```

template code to access that data

```
<ul>
{% for a,b,c,d in nd %}
    <li>{{a}}</li>
    <li>{{b}}</li>
    <li>{{a}}</li>
    <li>{{b}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

but it gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

I tried many ways and each time it was unsuccessful.I'm new to the Django framework. Please, someone, suggest a way to display them on the template web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are replacing your output list with the json dump output. you should use some other variable like `TempNewsData` as I used here (this is just your for-loop):

```
TempNewsData = pyData2['_source']

pyNewsData1 = json.dumps(TempNewsData)
pyNewsData2 = json.loads(pyNewsData1)

id = pyData2['_id']

headline = pyNewsData2['newsHeadline']

newsText = pyNewsData2['newsText']

date = pyNewsData2['date']



list = [id, headline, newsText, date]

newsData.append(list)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that.Now the error has gone